# Auto Increment ID number Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to auto increment a ID when adding new values to my sheet. I tried to create a list from my current ID list and it only counts until 5, so when auto incrementing it only get to a point and holds that number for every input.

Here is how I tried to get a list of the ID numbers but it does not get the whole list. What am I missing?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var row = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase1").getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
```

.getValue() gets the last value and with .alert() it shows on screen after button click

```
var row = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase1").getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValue();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(row);
```

This only gets like 5 values, say 0,1,2,3,4 ... there it gets stuck.

I manually add from 1 to 10 to see if it auto increments to 11 and it counts 6 repeatedly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you added doesn't give enough information to your code logic. Is this executed in a `onEdit` trigger? How do you get "the last ID"?

Comment: .getValue() gives me the last value, .getValues() shows only 5 of my whole list. For display purpose to see what i got i put the following code: SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(row);  this gives me an alert on the screen showing either my 5 numbers from 10 numbers depending on the .getValue() or getValues(), using this line: var row = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase1").getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValue(); and the .alert I get the last ID but only at number 5 even though I have 10 numbers in my list, hope this helps my question

Comment: `getValue()` returns the top-left value of the range, not the last. Or are you adding rows on top?

Comment: Could you add a read-only example of what you are doing? (Be careful to no add personal or sensible information)

Comment: I am creating a database that will save data once a day, but I want to assign a primary ID to each day without manually entering the ID, therefore creating a auto increment to the last value of the ID, should it be 10 the next ID should be 11. I do not want the user to enter a ID daily but the script should plus one the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'd like to have a unique ID for each row. You have multiple options depending on your requirements.

#### Way 1: A simple formula

If you are not changing the order or deleting (not simply emptying) rows, you can simply use the number of column as the value to set the ID. Simply add the formula `=ROW()` to assign a value to it.

#### Way 2: Using UUIDs

If you don't care about what value it is you may use an UUID instead. This would make it not depend on the values of other rows. You can get one using:

```js
  const uuid = Utilities.getUuid()
```

This is the most versatile option.

#### Way 3: Using properties to save the current value

If you need them to be an autoincremented number that only is set when using the script (i.e. no id is added manually), you can use properties to keep the count:

```js
function getNextId() {
  // Get properties
  const properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

  // Aquire the script lock. Prevents race condition
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.waitLock(2000)

  // Get the saved ID and save the next value
  // Properties are string so it has to convert the type
  const id = parseInt(properties.getProperty('id_seq') || 0)
  properties.setProperty('id_seq', (id+1).toString())

  // Release the script lock (allows other executions to continue)
  lock.releaseLock()

  // Return the result
  console.log(id)
  return id
}
```

To use it, you call it as you would do with the UUID:

```js
  const id = nextID()
```

Note that the algorithm needs to lock to prevent race conditions (if the script is executed in multiple instances at the same time).

This would be analogous to a sequence on a database.

#### Way 4: Biggest + 1

This adds a new row with only an ID. Needs to be used before adding the data. If the biggest number gets deleted, the same ID will be reused. Note that we also need to lock the entire operation and also need a flush to be 100% sure that another script would see the changes made by this one.

```js
function setNextId() {
  // Get spreadsheet
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]

  // Aquire the script lock. Prevents race condition
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.waitLock(2000)

  // Get value from last row
  const lastCell = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
  const values = lastCell.getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(Number.isInteger)
  const value = Math.max(...values)
  
  // Create new row
  const newCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1)
  newCell.setValue(value+1)

  // Ensure value is added before releasing the lock
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()

  // Release the script lock (allows other executions to continue)
  lock.releaseLock()
}
```

#### Way 5: Last row + 1

Similar to the last one but it simply looks the last row. This doesn't support reordering the rows.

```js
function setNextId() {
  // Get spreadsheet
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]

  // Aquire the script lock. Prevents race condition
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.waitLock(2000)

  // Get value from last row
  const lastCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1)
  const value = lastCell.getValue()

  // Create new row
  const newCell = lastCell.offset(1, 0)
  newCell.setValue(value+1)

  // Ensure value is added before releasing the lock
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()

  // Release the script lock (allows other executions to continue)
  lock.releaseLock()
}
```

### References

- [Utilities.getUuid() (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#getuuid)
- [Lock Service (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)
- [Properties Service (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [SpreadsheetApp.flush() (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)
- [Class Range (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thank you Martí, I used method 3 and it works perfectly. I had to .setValue(id) a column and then .getValue() to add to my database. Everything just works, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you doing wrong because it's hard to figure out what you doing at all.  We need a minimum reproducible example so that we can reproduce the problem that you are getting and then help you to solve it.

But in this line `var row = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase1").getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();`

The third parameter should be `ss.getLastRow()-2` it doesn't want the last row it wants the number of rows.